# Freemarker - Iterate through nested maps and nested lists

Tags: java, freemarker, template-engine

I have to iterate through a `List<Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>>>` and print all its content.

My problem is that each time I use map's bracket syntax ([like in the documentation](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_hash.html)) at nested levels I have a syntax issue. Could you show me how to handle nested levels for a type like `List<Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>>>` ?

I have tested this:

```
<!-- List<Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>>> -->
<#list myList as map1>

    <!-- Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>> -->
    <#list map1?keys as key1>
        My Key: ${key1}

        <!-- List<Map<String, String>> -->
        <#list map1[key1] as map2>


            <!-- Map<String, String> -->
            <#list map2?keys as key2>
                My Key: ${key2} | My Value: ${map2[key2]}
            </#list>
        </#list>
    </#list>
</#list>
```

And I have this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: The following has evaluated to null or missing:
==> map1[key1]  [in template "hello.html" at line 39, column 32]

----
Tip: It's the final [] step that caused this error, not those before it.
----
Tip: If the failing expression is known to be legally refer to something that's sometimes null or missing, either specify a default value like myOptionalVar!myDefault, or use <#if myOptionalVar??>when-present<#else>when-missing</#if>. (These only cover the last step of the expression; to cover the whole expression, use parenthesis: (myOptionalVar.foo)!myDefault, (myOptionalVar.foo)??
----

----
FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
    - Failed at: #list map1[key1] as map2  [in template "hello.html" at line 39, column 25]
----
```

I am using Freemarker [2.3.23](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.freemarker/freemarker/2.3.23). Thanks.

Comment: Can you quote the non-working template snippet?

Comment: I have updated my topic with the non-working template snippet :)

Comment: Have you checked what's the value of 'key1' where it fails?

Comment: Yes, I have checked 'key1' 's value, it's OK. The problem happens when I create a loop and try to iterate through 'map1', the '[ ]' syntax is not recognized.

Comment: The syntax is recognized, as the error message shows. I suspect that the value for that key is `null` in the `Map`.

Answer (score 0):

Though an old question, sharing the answer as the title is very generic and users can often land here looking for a solution. Point to note that the input is a `Map` even though our focus data type is a `List` and the list with data is added into the map with key `myList` which is same as mentioned in the template. This goes as per the library requirement quoted below -

> Generally, you want to use a Map or a JavaBean as the root-map (aka. data-model) parameter. The Map key-s or JavaBean property names will be the variable names in the template.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Object> input = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        List<Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>>> l1 = new ArrayList<>();
        Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>> m1 = new HashMap<>();
        List<Map<String, String>> l2 = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
        Map<String, String> m2 = new HashMap<String, String>();

        m2.put("m2", "m2v");
        l2.add(m2);
        m1.put("m1", l2);
        l1.add(m1);
        input.put("myList", l1);

        System.out.println(l1);

        Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
        try{
            FileTemplateLoader ftl = new FileTemplateLoader(new File("C:\\temp"));
            cfg.setTemplateLoader(ftl);
            Template temp = cfg.getTemplate("aa.ftlh");
            temp.process(input, new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, thanks but this do not answer to my question, I was looking for a FreeMarker template example with a complex List of Maps.

Comment: The code I shared works with the template you have provided in the question. Wont that help?

Comment: The code you share is Java code, I am looking for FreeMarker template code, because my FreeMarker template code does not work.

Comment: Let me be clear - Your template + my Java code works well. You do not need to change the template.